# What event happens when I select a sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to accomplish is fairly simple. When a user selects a sheet, I would like a message box to appear. Meaning: I'm currently viewing Sheet1, I click on the Sheet2 tab and a message pops up before I can do anything. I can't seem to find the event that fires when moving to a different sheet.

Events I've tried: `Workbook_SheetActivate` and `Worksheet_Activate`

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal sh As Object)
        MsgBox ("Example Message")
End Sub
```

Or

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
        MsgBox ("Example Message")
End Sub
```

I've done some googling and most things are about when cell values change or the cell selection changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    MsgBox "you never visit...you never call....you never write"
End Sub
```

However:

- code must be in the worksheet code area
- macros must be enabled
- events must be enabled

Comment: Thank you sir! I had macros and events enabled, but I had the code in a separate module

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following in the "ThisWorkbook" module to fire a message whenever you change sheets within the workbook.

```
Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    MsgBox Sh.Name & " activated!"
End Sub
```

This will solve the problem without having to add `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` to every worksheet's code module.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to all the worksheet events available in Excel:

http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/event.htm

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() 
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)     -- (additional examples) 
     Cancel = True   'turn off Edit mode when using “Edit directly in a cell” 
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean) 
    Cancel = True   'turn off Edit mode when using “Edit directly in a cell” 
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    Application.EnableEvents = False   'should be part of Change macro 
    Application.EnableEvents = True   'should be part of Change macro 
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate() 
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink) 
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
```

Doesn't `Worksheet_Activate` work for you?

Comment: Yes, that was the correct event. I just had it in the wrong place. Thanks for providing this information though!

Comment: Excellent, glad to have helped!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the event in the worksheet that is being activated - that is, if you put it is sheet 2, it will fire only when that sheet is opened.
This worked in sheet 2 of my workbook.
Sub worksheet_activate()
MsgBox "activated!"
End Sub